Science-fiction story about Earth people developing telepathy and eventually getting depopulated
A science fiction story, where some space explorers are to embark on a space journey. Just before the journey, the people of the Earth are showing unexpected signs of telepathy.
The space exploration employs sub-light rockets, and thus the spaceship returns to Earth after about 30-40 years. Upon arriving, they find that Earth is deserted. No radio signals, no sign of technology. They find some old Earth people, who tell the returning Earthmen that the effects of sudden developments of telepathy have effectively decimated the people. Their minds could not cope with so many thoughts. Even the children perished.
The old people suggested that the returning Earthmen, who had not developed telepathy, to try to propagate life anew. But the returning Earthmen also were old, thus ultimately, mankind was doomed to be finished on Earth.

Please take a look at Short story: telepathy has all but destroyed the female population of Earth. Returning astronauts offer hope of repopulation to tell us if this is the same one. If it is, we can mark this question as a duplicate, which will then serve as a signpost to user14111's excellent answer to the earlier question :)

Yes, the referred link is the correct one. It is the same, and my question may please be marked as duplicate. But first, many many thanks.

Excellent! Enjoy the re-read then :)
